# Display graph in jupyter using vis.js

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, vis.js

I need some help. 
I want to display a graph in jupyter notebook with vis.js.

What is the easiest way to do it? 
I tried to do it according to this post:
https://www.codementor.io/isaib.cicourel/visjs-visualization-in-jupyter-notebook-phgb3fjv0

However, downloading the package and modifying my jupyter_config seems odd to me. 
Is there a better / easier way to do it and if, how? 
I tried it with unpkg but failed.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-pyvis-within-jupyter-notebook ?